# Переход с React Router V2.x в V4.x

Tags: reactjs, react-router, ecmascript-6

После обновления `React Router V2.x` на `V4.x` все маршруты ведут на главную страницу.

Вот маршрут на `V2.x`:

```
import {Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

const routes = <Route component={App}>
  <Route path="/results" component={Results} />
  <Route path="/" component={Voting} />
</Route>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>{routes}</Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

А это маршруты на `V4.x`:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, hashHistory, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

const withAppLayout = Component => props => <App><Component {...props} /></App>

const routes = <Switch>
    <Route path="/results" component={withAppLayout(Results)} />
    <Route path="/" component={withAppLayout(Voting)} />
</Switch>
        ;

ReactDOM.render(
        <Router component={App} history={hashHistory}>
            {routes}
        </Router>,
        document.getElementById('app')
        );
```

Кто то сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Comment: Не уверен что причина в этом, но в v4 используют `render` для лейпута. Тут есть подробное описание https://simonsmith.io/reusing-layouts-in-react-router-4/

Comment: Нельзя просто так взять и перейти с одной мажорной версии реакт роутера на другую, они каждый раз его полностью переписывают меняя всю идеологию и API нахрен

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму ну вот я не просто взял и установил четвертую версию, я переписал свой код как в доках прочитал но не хера не работает.